# Find a lower bound for a function with a cosine.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I have a function $F(z_1,z_2) := z_1^2\cos^2(z_2)+\frac{3}{4}z_2^2$.

I need to show that $\forall \alpha > 0\, \exists \gamma > 0\, \forall z\, \|z\| \geq \alpha \implies F(z_1,z_2) \geq \gamma $.

Aside from using Lagrange multipliers for this function $F$ with restriction $z_1^2 + z_2^2 \geq \alpha^2$ that give a basically unsolvable (?) equation over $z_2$:
$-(\alpha^2 - z_2^2)\sin(2z_2) + \frac{3}{2}z_2 -z_2\cos^2(z_2) = 0$ do you guys have any other ideas I could use here?

I'm asking this because this is an example taken from a book so I feel like it should not be that hard, maybe some classic estimates or inequalities would work here, but I don't know many. I have tried Cauchy–Schwarz but that's basically the extents of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two cases.

Case 1. $z_2 <\pi/4$: Use the identity $\cos^2(x) = \frac12 (1 + \cos(2x))$. This allows to write
$$
F(z_1,z_2) = z_1^2\cos^2(z_2)+\frac{3}{4}z_2^2 = \frac12 z_1^2 + \frac12 z_1^2 \cos(2 z_2)+\frac{3}{4}z_2^2\\
\ge \frac12 z_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}z_2^2 = \frac12 \|z\|^2 \ge \frac12 \alpha^2 
$$
Case 2. $z_2 \ge \pi/4$:
$$
F(z_1,z_2) = z_1^2\cos^2(z_2)+\frac{3}{4}z_2^2  \ge \frac{3}{4}z_2^2 \ge \frac{3 \pi^2}{64} 
$$

Clearly, if $\alpha < \pi/4$, then case 2 never arises.

If no notion of $z_2$ is available, the  required bound is $F(z_1,z_2) \ge \gamma = \min \{ \frac12 \alpha^2, \frac{3 \pi^2}{64} \}$.